# How to measure the permittivity of a gas sensor?

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

I looking for a simple method to measure the permittivity of a gas sensor silicone.

Comment: This looks like an engineering problem so you need to post it on the appropriate SE site.

Comment: http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5980-2862EN.pdf. Simple, sort of, cheap... not so much. On the other hand, you can basically build a homebrew version of these instruments at home... reinventing the wheel is always fun.

Comment: I would close because of insufficient effort. The OP is basically asking us to do all the work for him without showing anything that he has done himself and why it didn't work for him.